# Inputs aren't running correctly

Tags: python

What am I doing wrong here with my inputs? Every time I try to run the program python will say that the argument is on line 2.

```
reservationHour = int(input("Enter the hour portion of your desired",\
                        "reservation in military time (0-23): "))
```

Thank you for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: What error exactly are you getting? Can you paste it here please?

Comment: did you debug your input without int () cast

Comment: You're passing 2 strings to the `input` method

Comment: Remove the `,` and the backslash at the end of the first line and it will (probably) work.

Comment: @MSeifert No it won't

Comment: @Simon Did you test it?

Comment: @MSeifert Yep `unexpected character after line continuation character` By that it means the backslash I think.

Comment: @Simon But when you remove the backslash there's no "line continuation character". So the exception doesn't really make sense. Are you sure you removed `,` and the backslash?

Comment: @MSeifert Ah I forgot that. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` accepts at most one argument. You are passing it two arguments.

Try removing the comma, and it will probably work. Though you will probably want to add a space after `desired` or before `reservation`.

Better still, you could try using a triple-quoted (multi-line) string, thereby introducing a newline into the prompt. The code would look like this:

```
reservationHour = int(input("""Enter the hour portion of your desired
reservation in military time (0-23): """))
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma, an `input` in python can only take one argument.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the comma! The `\` allows the `input()` on a new line however the `,` splits the string into two strings.  This will generate an error since `input()` can only hold one statement.